# IBM/Lotus Notes Developer View

Tags: lotus-notes

I appreciate this might seem like incomplete information but I dont have full information on this.

I've been given a number of NSF files to try get the data out of. I have downloaded the IBM Notes Demo. When I open one of the files, I get two colums that look like a mapping between two integers.

If I then highlight one of the rows and go to Create>Developers Form, I can see the full information for one of the records. We have tens of thousands of records and I would like to be able to see them all at once like a table view.

The system that the files came from has been decomissioned so we cant run it properly to access the data.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: "Create > Developers Form? "  I think I've used every version of Lotus Notes that has been released in the past 22 years, and I don't recall ever seeing a menu pick like that. I know you said the "IBM Notes Demo", but what exactly is the version of the software that you are opening that file with?

Comment: And BTW, even if the server has been decommissioned, yes you probably can properly access the data. Lotus Notes has always used exactly the same file format on both the server and client side, and a client has always been able to work with a file that is an exact replica of the file on the server. (The exception would be if the server has been configured with one of a few technologies that cause some of the data to be stored outside of the actual NSF file. But then again, if you don't actually have the complete data, you've got no chance anyhow. I'm assuming that's not the case.)

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I'm guessing that 'Developers Form' was the name of the only form in that database.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz  Thanks for the comments, this is the first time ive used Lotus Notes. It might well be a form on the database i'm working with. I'm pretty sure all the data is in the database because i can view the data one record at a time. I believe the version is Notes 9 social edition.

Answer (score 3):

Without having somebody to explain, what is in that NSFs you will have no chance to get the data out.

NSFs are document databases, that can contain a large amount of unstructured data.

This data can be "visible" using a view, but there are not necessary views for all kind of data.

Knowing LotusScript (a programming language that is very similar to VisualBasic) it is no problem to export the data as CSV, Excel, into a relational database or even as structured text or HTML, but the first step is to KNOW, what data you want to export.

Analysing a NSF- file without knowing its internal structures and without knowing the basics about NSF- Databases (what are forms, views, documents, items) is almost impossible, while an experienced Lotus Notes / Domino developer can extract data within minutes.

So the best advice to give you: Find an expert for Lotus Notes Databases and let HIM export the data, otherwise this will be a very long task to do.

Comment: I have a tool that export documents in a Notes database as XML, incluidng attachments and embedded images. More info about it here: http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter  I will put up a download of the demo version within a few days. Check back soon.

Comment: @Torsten-Link Thanks for your answer.  We do know the columns that are in the file, as what is displayed in the develops form shows them all. From your answer, it sounds like we need to create a new view to see the data in a different way, is that correct? A number of my colleagues are very proficient in T-SQL, is lotus script of a similar nature?

Comment: Lotus Notes is in NO WAY similar to an SQL database... You need to know the structures of data in a database to know how to write the code to get it.

Comment: Thanks, we've actually managed to use the export feature to export to a format with different encoding. Which has allowed us to view the records in notepad. Thanks for all your comments.